# CocoonJS - File input crashes on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, cocoonjs

I'm building an HTML5 app that I want to distribute to iOS using CocoonJS. On a certain page I want the user to be able to upload an image:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" />
```

This works fine when I open my app in Safari on iPhone, but it crashes when I open it from the CocoonJS app.

Even when I just create a simple html page and run it from launcher it crashes.

I don't understand why I haven't found anyone else experiencing this issue..

Hope someone can help me out here!

Comment: they are probably compiling the app with xcode 5, it has a bug that make the app crash when you use input file on iOS 8. Contact them. They should use xcode 6 and ios 8 SDK

Comment: What runtime are you using to execute your app? Canvas+, WebView or WebView+? We are using XCode 6. Could you provide the simples test case possible? Just a simple HTML that makes the CocoonJS Launcher to crash. Please contact Ludei's support anyway.

Comment: It crashes both on WebView and WebView+. Creating a custom launcher to run it solves my problem, the main CocoonJS launcher fails. I've already filed an issue with a simple test case: http://support.ludei.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201555305-Bug-File-input-crashes-on-iPhone-5-iOS8